# resize UIImage programmatically doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I was trying to resize my image programmatically to adapt to the screen's size, but when I build my app, the image won't even show. I just see a blank screen, does anyone know what I did wrong?

This is my code (learned that from some other threads about resizing images):

```
class ViewControllerSport: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var FotoSport: UIImageView!

let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    FotoSport.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: screen.width * 0.5, height: screen.width * 0.5)
    FotoSport.image = UIImage(named: "Blokker")


}
```

Comment: Just a quick note on the naming convention you are using, classes should be named with UpperCaseLetters whilst variables should use lowerCaseLetters.

Comment: Regarding the image view, are you using layout constraints?

Comment: You're completely right about the upper- and lowercase, it must've been a quick mistake in this image. Not in this View Controller, I hadn't done anything in it so far except for adding the Image View and writing this code.

Comment: Check output for this method "UIImage(named: "Blokker")" - does it return something?

Comment: Well it should, I have an image named "Blokker", and it should work, because I've used it in other view controllers as well. For example in this code ` horecaImageView.image = UIImage(named: detailHoreca.name)`, in which the "detailHoreca.name" is a name of the picture, which works with "Blokker" too..

Comment: "Blokker" image type is jpeg ? then you should include the type also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function resizes an image. It takes two arguments: the image and the desired size.

```
func ResizeImage(image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * heightRatio, size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSizeMake(size.width * widthRatio,  size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.drawInRect(rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

**Usage :**

```
self.ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "MyImage.png")!, targetSize: CGSizeMake(320.0, 700.0))
```

Reference link :: [**Resize image**](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2015/12/how-to-resize-image-in-swift-in-ios.html)

**Swift 3.0:**

```
func ResizeImage(_ image: UIImage, targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let size = image.size

    let widthRatio  = targetSize.width  / image.size.width
    let heightRatio = targetSize.height / image.size.height

    // Figure out what our orientation is, and use that to form the rectangle
    var newSize: CGSize
    if(widthRatio > heightRatio) {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * heightRatio, height: size.height * heightRatio)
    } else {
        newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * widthRatio, height: size.height * widthRatio)
    }

    // This is the rect that we've calculated out and this is what is actually used below
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: newSize.width, height: newSize.height)

    // Actually do the resizing to the rect using the ImageContext stuff
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 1.0)
    image.draw(in: rect)
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

*Usage :*

```
self.ResizeImage(UIImage(named: "MyImage.png")!, targetSize: CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 700.0))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, check that the `UIImage(named: "Blokker")` is returning an image or nil. 
If it's returning an image, in order to scale an image in UIImageView you can use one of these:

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

ScaleToFill just scales the image.

AspectFit and AspectFill scales the image conserving it's aspect ratio.

Fit will scale the image until it will be all shown. Fill will scale the image until one of its sides equals one of UIImageView sides.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Art/scale_aspect.jpg