# swift xcode change size for navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, xcode

wanting to set the size for the image that show in the simulator as it comes up far to big i've tried many thing to no avail ?

```
func CancelButton(){
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: 
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "HOME BUTTON BLACK").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleCancel))

}

func handleCancel() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}// handleCancel
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a smaller image!

You can either do this in code, or replace the current image with a smaller one.

For bar button items, the best size is around 25x25, so try to resize it to that.

To do it in code, you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37786213/5133585).